# Talend : how to change context mode for all jobs?

Tags: talend

I am now working on Talend Open Studio.
I have a job composed by around 40 jobs.

I worked in DEV context mode, and I wanted to try in PROD mode. But I wasted much time on changing values of contexte from DEV to PROD.

I had to open each job and manually change the mode of the job [image: step1]

After, I had to select each tRunJob and change the mode too[image: step2]

Is there a tip to change all the context mode for all the jobs ? Because in my case I had to change approximatly 100 comboboxes !
Editing each context by selecting PROD as "Default" did not work.[image: context]

Thank you for your help.
Damien K.

Answer (score 1):

Damien, i don't think you need to open each child job and change the context mode. Just change the default context environment in master job, and in each tRunjob in master job only plus you also need to check option "Transmit Whole context" in each tRunjob. That's it. No need to open each child job.

Comment: Also make sure that the contexts of your subjobs are available in the master job, else transmit whole context won't propagate the values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to check "Transmit Whole Context" for my subjobs in the main job, but even if I select DEV or PROD on the main job, my other jobs do not change ... Furthermore, I dont want to transmit all the time values of context, in majority of case, I just want to change DEV/PROD. (To change queries and database connection)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you call the child job through tRunJob in non dynamic mode, then you don't need to touch "Default context environment", but should check option in build dialog:[image]
   Don't forget to rebuild the job when you change the context, the context switch modifies the command line for top-level job as well as *modify generated Java code to propagate new context to all children*
2. If you call the child job through tRunJob in dynamic mode, then you really should change "Default context environment" for each child job or to override context variables of child job by identical context variables of parent job with using option "Transmit Whole context"